# How can I show the full weight paint?

Tags: armature, weight-painting, surface-deform, weight-paint-mode

I am trying to pose a model I found online by adding an armature.
I created the armature and applied automatic weights.

I am able to move the armatures but there are deformation.
[image: Armature Posing Deformations]

I try to correct the weight of the armature using weight paint but I am unable to see the full model's weight paint.
[image: Weight map only showing top of head]

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have to select the vertex group in the object data properties to see each bone's weight paint. You can never see "all" weight paint because it makes no sense because each bone has "normally" different weights on each vertex.

Comment: The first thing I'd do with any mesh I'd found online is to go into Edit mode, select All in Vertex mode then hit 'M' > Merge by Distance. Then try parenting with automatic weights again.

Comment: Thank you both. Merging Vertexes by Distance and using the Vertex Groups helped a lot. They were exactly what I needed after unhiding the model in edit mode using Alt+H.
After that I was able to to see all the vertexes in edit mode and merge them. Then I used the Vertex Groups to go through each entry and find where the weight was being applied incorrectly -- the left thumb had a significant amount of weight on the chin ( definitely from a previous mistake of mine ).

Thank you both for the replies !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance the reason the rest of the model wasn't showing is because it was hidden in edit mode. I used `Alt+H` to unhide the model in Edit / Weight Painting. Which I tried after reading [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189800/object-mesh-is-disappearing-in-edit-mode-but-is-not-hidden) post.

After that I used Merge by Distance to merge the vertexes as recommended by [@John Eason](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/104232/john-eason) to clean up the model a little. -- I believe this also helped solve the fingers after I re-applied automatic weights ( next step )

I then applied Automatic Weights again to the model. From there I used the Weight Paint and Vertex Groups to see the weight of the individual armature bones -- as mentioned by [@Chris](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86978/chris) -- and was able to find that the left thumb was applied to the chin ( definitely because of a previous mistake of mine ) and fixed the issue.

With these fixes the model moves as expected when manipulating the armature.