Parts of mesh disappear in Edit Mode
I imported an alembic file from Clo3d and it has some parts that I would like to delete. The problem is that when I got into Edit Mode to delete them, they just disappear.


Download .blend from WeTransfer

Press Alt+H in Edit Mode. If that doesn't work please see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189800/object-mesh-is-disappearing-in-edit-mode-but-is-not-hidden

also make sure that you are in Vertex select mode, if you are in Face select mode you won't see isolate vertices or edges

Tried to unhide and went to the other question and tried the solutions, none seemed to work.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

weird, I can't see what you show in your screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/sPPhX8q/1.jpg

does it still have the animation?? if so can u send me the file, that way i already have it without the parts i didnt want

I found why it doesnt appear in others devices. The dress is directly connected to CLO3D (where i made the dress) therefore you only have the mesh but not the animation, and thats probably why you can't also see the little parts outside de dress.
